# All Cucumber tests getting skipped

Tags: maven, junit, cucumber

When I am running my cucumber tests in a Maven Project via J-unit Test Runner, all the tests are getting skipped.

I have used Step-Definition Package path in the glue attribute but it seems the step definition file is not getting recognized and output console is asking me to implement missing steps (though i have implemented all of them)

I am using the "Natural 0.7.6" plugin for cucumber. Tried with the "cucumber eclipse plugin" as well, it didn't work.

Comment: Please provide a dump of your directory structure and your associated code.

Comment: Thanks Mike for your  valuable response .Actually the issue was with a maven plugin which was either incompatible/deprecated .Deleting that plugin from .m2 repository and updating the Maven project thereafter resolved the issue .